# Web based animation libraries for educational purpose

Tags: javascript, animation

I am thinking a creating some web based animations for representing some CS concepts in OS, Algorithm, Programming... Till now I think of using Javascript for that. Looking for some suggestions regarding that.

Is there an other good alternative?
What are the good libraries available for this specific purpose?

Comment: Why would you use a programming language for animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a javascript library to display animated data, you could try [d3](http://d3js.org/) which has some great features.

If you're looking for a clean way to draw animations that can be viewed in-browser, you might look at [processing](http://processing.org/)? It's more oriented towards animation and display, plus you can use [`processing.js`](http://processingjs.org/) to run it in any (modern?) browser.